# Cefsharp multiple BrowserSubProcesses utilizing all memory

Tags: chromium, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

My application is creating Chromium webbrowser instances to load different customers. The problem is that for each webbrowser instance a render process is created, which consumes 80-110 mb's of memory. All the customers are stored on the same site, so I have enabled "Process Per Site" as the description of this would fix my issue. I also tested loading 3 ChromiumWebBrowser instances loading the address google.com, which also resulted in 3 different render processes being created, each consuming 80-110 mb's of memory.

Is there anything that can be done regarding multiple render processes consuming lots of memory, or is this unpreventable?

Comment: What version are you using? What command line args did you use? Are you using the default RequestContext for all browsers? Memory usage per process is as I would expect.

Comment: Hello @amaitland , im using version v79.1.360 of cefsharp. 

For command line args, I added: 
cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("--process-per-site", "1"); 

We are using the default RequestContext for all browsers.

Comment: Version 87 is the current supported version,  I don't remember what process model was default for version 79. Generally speaking I'd strongly advise against changing from the default as other models aren't tested or supported from a Chromium embedded framework (CEF) stand point. How does version 87 behave with the default process model?

Comment: I upgraded to the newest stable Cefsharp version, and it still does not work. Do you have any other ideas of things that could be wrong for process per site model not to work in a project?

Comment: Also noticed something that might be of help. In my project im trying to load a specific customer site from the start. And I just tested, and it looks like if I start from google.com and then try to access the customer site all the processes get's linked together (process-per-site working). But when i try to load the browser with that customer site from the start it does not work. Any idea what could cause that?

Comment: As I said process-per-site is not supported by CEF, only the default process model should be used. https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/site-isolation describes the current model, we currently have disable-site-isolation-trials set by default to workaround some CEF issues, you can try removing it from CefCommandLineArgs collection. Isolating Certain Sites section of the link above might be useful in your case.

Comment: I just have to really thank you @amaitland for the help your giving me, I appreciate it! 

As to your previous comment, in that case im going to try to find a fix which does not include changing from the default process model since that is not supported. I tried to disable site isolation trials, by adding this: settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("--disable-site-isolation-trials");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process"); 
It did not fix issue.
Question, do you know what the expected behaviour is on binded objects when procceses merge?

Comment: To be clear,  site isolation trials are disabled currently as there's a few rare issues that still need to be fixed. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/87/CefSharp.Core.Runtime/CefSettingsBase.h#L55 if you change your code to CefCommandLineArgs.Remove("disable-site-isolation-trials") then you should be running the same process model as chromium uses by default. What exactly is process merging exactly?

Comment: I see, I tried using the provided remove argument instead but it did not make any difference as it seems that I have more processes now. Also tested adding the "--isolate-origins=www.example.com" which also, unfortunately, did not fix the issue. With the process merging I meant that with site isolation the different SubBrowserProcesses merge together into 1 bigger process. I'm wondering when we have bound objects with javascript, what is the expected behaviour when these individual SubBrowserProcceses merge into 1 big process?

Comment: How does your site behave when you load it in multiple tabs in Chrome? For bound objects long as the name you choose is unique for the object type then you shouldn't need to worry.

Comment: You should be able to load chrome://process-internals in a ChromiumWebBrowser instance to see if site isolation is enabled.

Comment: site-per-process is detailed at https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2498/add-support-for-site-per-process and https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/site-isolation just to be clear site-per-process is different to process-per-site, I know the words are the same in a different order. They are two different process models.